# LibreOffice highlight cells if they are the same as a specific range

Tags: search, find, libreoffice

[Master and Step Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccRy1.jpg)

Hello, I'm using A4-E4 as a "Master" code, and incrementally using A5-A8 to replace A4, B5-B8 to replace B4, etc etc first replacing one number of the "master", then two different numbers, etc until I have basically every combination. At some point the same number as the "master" is going to be generated. I have the numbers separated into groups of 16 on individually sheets for a total of 64 sheets. Obviously at some point the same number "43254" is going to generate on one of the sheets. Is there a way to search/highlight that number automatically upon generation? I've found that I can do conditional formatting to search for a specific cell, but not a range of cells. Like compare "A4-E4" to every set of five adjacent numbers in all the sheets, then highlight it. I have no idea if this is possible, but I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Select cells A4 through E4 and go to *Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage.*  Apply style `Good` if *Formula is*:

```
CONCATENATE($A4;$B4;$C4;$D4;$E4)="43254"
```

So `43254` matches.

[image: highlighted]

And `43253` does not match.

[image: not highlighted]

This is more complex than first appears.  The following explanation may be difficult to understand if you do not have much experience with conditional formatting.

The formula gets evaluated 5 times, once for each of the cells.

Normally, rather than always indicating cell A4, Calc would interpret `A4` as the currently evaluated cell (because we selected cells starting from A4).  And `B4` would indicate the cell to the right of the current cell that is evaulated.  So for example, if such a conditional formatting formula were filled to cell D7, then `A4` would actually indicate cell D7, and `B4` would indicate cell E7.

However, our formula uses `$A4` instead.  The `$` tells Calc that we always want column A even if the formatting is for column B or C et cetera.

One outcome of this is that the formula can be filled down or up but not left or right.  If it is filled down one row for example, `$A4` refers to column A but the current row, which would be cell A5.